# Magento Catalog Search not display current store products only

Tags: multistore, catalog, catalogsearch

I have one website - multiple stores

- Store 1 : Sports Store (*sports.mydomain.com*)
- Store 2 : Music Store  (*music.mydomain.com*)

My problem is when i search from any of store, products displayed from both stores. I want only products from current store.

Comment: How have you got the stores set up? Is it just two store views or have you got 2 stores each assigned to a different root category?

Comment: Yes Root Categories of both stores are different

Comment: What version of Magento?

Comment: Magento Version 1.9.2

Comment: Are you searching frontend or admin?

Comment: Front end section.

Answer (score 1):

For the Sports Store you have to disable all music products from product grid
and for the music store you have to disable all sports products. you can do it from product Grid.

```
Admin > Catalog > Manage Products
```

1. Choose Store View : `Sports Store` And 
   select All Music Store Products if there and from mass action select `Change Status` to `Disable`.
2. Choose Store View : `Music store` And 
   select All Sports Store Products if there and from mass action select `Change Status` to `Disable`.
3. Once all done do the *Re-Indexing* for all.

Comment: How can we do programatically, means change in search query.